# Deploying multiple rails application in a single digital ocean droplet using capistrano+nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I have a rails application running on a digital ocean server with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx .the deployed with Capistrano was easy now running with ease.Now I'm thinking to deploy another application to the same server using capistrano, After many research i'm not getting any proper solutions for my doubts or cant find any best tutorials for this.

What are the essential steps to look after before deploying the second application to the server?

Which nginx port the second application should listen to, 80 is default and the first application is already listening to that.?

How to access the second application after if deployed to the same droplet, now i can access the first application using the ip.?

Answer (score 3):

For each app, you need to make sure whatever server you are using is listening on a different socket.

After that, you have to add another server block in Nginx configurations like below,

```
upstream app_one {
    # Path to server1 SOCK file
}

upstream app_two {
    # Path to server2 SOCK file
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /root/app_one/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_one;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
} 

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name IP;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /root/app_two/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_two;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: `server_name domain_app_two.com;` currently i don't have any domains, how to access these apps using ips

Comment: Then you should pass IP of your instance in the server name and use different ports for different applications if feasible.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: do the above configuration in a single nginx.conf file ??? or separate for each application???

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes or limited-user-count applications you can have as many domains as you wish. You'd simply add to `/etc/hosts` (assuming you have Linux box)

```
NGINX.IP.ADDR.ESS domain-one.com
NGINX.IP.ADDR.ESS domain-two.com
```

Then use these server names in corresponding server blocks in your Nginx config file. In this case you can use the same port number. Other users of these applications should make the same changes on their boxes.

Moreover if such users are grouped within the same LAN you can configure fake zones on your DNS and use it instead of `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: i don't have any domains like 'domain-one.com' or 'domain-two.com' i use to access the first application using the ip DO gave me.now i need to deploy to the same droplet,i deployed the application but clinched with few configuration errors.

Comment: I understand that you don't have these domains, it's just names of resources and these names are valid only on box with modified `/etc/hosts`. Settings in this file takes precedence over default name resolution. Try to add in `/etc/hosts` `stackoverflow.com` with IP address of your DO server and specify `server_name stackoverflow.com;` in the Nginx server block, then pointing to `stackoverflow.com`in your browser you'll get your DO application. You can use **any** domain names this way.