# setup bitnami redmine as centralized setup

Tags: windows, webserver, redmine, centralized

I have installed bitnami redmine and able to access it via http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx ip and port , i need to set it up as a centralized one or need the http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx to be accessible by all the one in my organisation. how to configure the setup kindly guide

Comment: You need a dns entry pointing towards your Redmine server IP

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725755/11801415) answer and comments